# Hazelcast with openjdk-15

Tags: java, docker, hazelcast

How I can run hazelcast with java15 ? I am using usercodedeployment so I need to install my own classes in java 15. Now I got error:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-04-08T23:34:43.129+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Hazelcast nepripojen","logger_name":"org.my.data.HazelcastInstanceWrapper","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"com.hazelcast.client.UndefinedErrorCodeException: Class name: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, Message: org/my/data/MyData has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:878)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassSource.define(ClassSource.java:52)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.defineClassFromClient(ClassLocator.java:135)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.defineClassesFromClient(ClassLocator.java:107)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.UserCodeDeploymentService.defineClasses(UserCodeDeploymentService.java:74)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.operation.DeployClassesOperation.run(DeployClassesOperation.java:49)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.call(Operation.java:184)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:256)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:237)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:452)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:166)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:136)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n","SERVERNAME":"rob-cache-8448d476d6-l9k2j"}
```

I check that hazelcast support this version and when I check official [dockerfile](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker/blob/master/hazelcast-enterprise/Dockerfile) there is java11. Is there also version with java 15 or I need to create my own dockerfile with java 15 ?

Comment: Making your own docker file isn't going to help when the underlying executable isn't compatible

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, the official Docker image uses Java 11. Note that your link points to the Enterprise version, the OSS version is [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker/blob/master/hazelcast-oss/Dockerfile).

Because your code has been compiled with Java 15, it's not possible for the Java 11 runtime on the server-side to execute it.

Creating your own Dockerfile with a Java runtime 15+ will solve this issue.